# How to handle this error when requesting data from watchkit

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

Any hints about this error.

> 2015-06-10 20:12:10.612 **APPNAME** [10339:1886873] *** Assertion failure in -[UIWatchKitExtensionRequestAction sendResponse:], /SourceCache/BaseBoard/BaseBoard-98.3/BaseBoard/BSAction.m:221
>
> 2015-06-10 20:12:10.624 **APPNAME** [10339:1886873] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'this request has been neutered - you can't call -sendResponse: twice nor after encoding it'
>
> *** First throw call stack:
>
> (0x185cf42d8 0x1974c00e4 0x185cf4198 0x186ba8ed4 0x18c1daab4 0x1005c4f94 0x1005cf08c 0x18c1daa08 0x18ae1dab4 0x18c0e7778 0x1005c4fd4 0x1005c4f94 0x1005d2b54 0x1005d4248 0x197cf122c 0x197cf0ef0)
>
> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Where is this being thrown. What code is making this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this error is generated in your `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest` code. It often happens when you accidentally call `reply()` twice for the same request. Go through your code, set some breakpoints, and ensure that doesn't happen.